URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
Getting the below error when trying to execute the below script in gitlab pipeline.

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
/builds/testing/testing-prj/testing-api/scripts/test_api.sh:
13: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")

This is the script. It happens on the first curl command when I added debugging statement.
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tag=1.66.0-test
image=vm/search-quote-service
private_token=glpat-pwd
project=2134
echo $project
repo_id=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$project/registry/repositories" | jq -c --arg regex ".*\\$image$" '.[] | select(.path | test($regex))'.id)
echo $repo_id
if [[ $(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $private_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$project/registry/repositories/$repo_id/tags/$tag" | jq -r '.name') == "$tag" ]]; then
  echo "$tag exists"
else
  echo "$tag does not exist"
fi

Anyone knows why this error happening?

I can't reproduce the problem.  One possibility is that there are invisible characters in the code that are causing it to break.  CR characters in Windows line endings are a common issue.  See Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it? and Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?.

Run the script with '-vx' - you can see the expanded command. Most likely, the first curl failed (authentication ? ), resulting in "funny" repo_id. Consider quoting "repo_id" (in echo statement ), to avoid surprises.
